# Making dynamic click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On a page, I have multiple button but with same class, and I want to add class `loading` on each button click.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $(".btn").addClass('loading');
    alert("button 1 clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" cass="btn btn-test">Button 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-test">Button 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-test2">Button 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-test2">Button 1</a>
</div>
```

How to handle for different button clicked so each time button is clicked the same alert will appear?

Comment: Use `$(this).addClass('loading');`

Comment: Do you want to add loading on each button when any of the buttons is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `this` operator. Within the below example, `this` refers to the current object being handled.

See [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

```
<div>
  <a href="#" cass="btn btn-test">Button 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-test">Button 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-test2">Button 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-test2">Button 1</a>
</div>

$(".btn").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('loading');
    alert("button 1 clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `this` keyword it refers to the object its within in this case the element clicked

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
    this.classList.add('loading')
});
```

```css
.loading {background: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-test">Button 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-test">Button 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-test2">Button 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-test2">Button 1</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this keywoard `this`

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('loading');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn").on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('loading');
    alert("button clicked");
});
```

Give them the same class and it should work.

Comment: Yea, my bad. Works either way